# In CDP how to update OneViewofProfile Id through (VisitorId, browserID)?

Tags: cloudera-cdh, cdp, cloudera-cdp

anyone from CDP certified guide me on this. what is the better approach to update CDP profile id, **and how these below use cases are same. When 2 user are using same device, do they got the same visitor Id ?**

**One CDP platform I visit there i saw**
through VisitorId they are identifing update_or_create(OneViewofProfile Id) in CDP
here browser Id is not creating new in incognito mode.
Visitor id creating always new. in incognito

**In Sitecore I saw**
Through browserID they get refId(OneViewofProfile Id) and then update OneViewofProfile Id through refId
here browser Id is getting newly create in incognito mode
Visitor id creating always new. in incognito

your guidance will be highly appreciated

Thanks

I tried multiple CDP platforms.